# Unable to get memory or num_cpus from template in Terraform VSphere

Tags: terraform, vsphere

While trying to allocate memory and num_cpus for a virtual machine in VSphere, I am trying to extract the memory and num_cpus from the template. But I am getting an error while trying to do so.
Here is my resource:

```
data "vsphere_virtual_machine" "template" {
name = var.vm-template-name
datacenter_id = data.vsphere_datacenter.dc.id
}

resource "vsphere_virtual_machine" "vm" {
  count = var.vm-count
  name = "${var.vm-name}-${count.index + 1}"
  resource_pool_id = data.vsphere_compute_cluster.cluster.resource_pool_id
  datastore_id = data.vsphere_datastore.datastore.id
  folder = var.vm-folder
  #####Problem Area############################################
  num_cpus = data.vsphere_virtual_machine.template.num_cpus
  memory = data.vsphere_virtual_machine.template.memory
  #############################################################
  guest_id = data.vsphere_virtual_machine.template.guest_id
  scsi_type = data.vsphere_virtual_machine.template.scsi_type
  firmware = data.vsphere_virtual_machine.template.firmware

  network_interface {
    network_id = data.vsphere_network.network.id
    adapter_type = data.vsphere_virtual_machine.template.network_interface_types[0]
  }

  disk {
      label            = "disk0"
      size             = data.vsphere_virtual_machine.template.disks.0.size
      eagerly_scrub    = data.vsphere_virtual_machine.template.disks.0.eagerly_scrub
      thin_provisioned = data.vsphere_virtual_machine.template.disks.0.thin_provisioned
    }

  clone {
    template_uuid = data.vsphere_virtual_machine.template.id

    customize {
        windows_options {
          auto_logon_count = 2
          computer_name = "HarshitDev"
          organization_name = "Philips"
        }
      }
  }
}
```

And here is the error I am getting when I run 'terraform validate':

> Error: Unsupported attribute
>
> on main.tf line 39, in resource "vsphere_virtual_machine" "vm":
>   39: num_cpus = data.vsphere_virtual_machine.template.num_cpus
>
> This object has no argument, nested block, or exported attribute named
>   "num_cpus".
>
> Error: Unsupported attribute
>
> on main.tf line 40, in resource "vsphere_virtual_machine" "vm":
>   40: memory = data.vsphere_virtual_machine.template.memory
>
> This object has no argument, nested block, or exported attribute named
>   "memory".

Comment: Do you have reason to believe it should? According to the documentation, it does not. https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/vsphere/d/virtual_machine.html#attribute-reference

Answer (score 0):

num_cpus has not been exposed in the [vsphere_virtual_machine resource](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-vsphere/blob/master/vsphere/data_source_vsphere_virtual_machine.go#L13).

Someone has started work on it ([see here](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-vsphere/compare/master...brian57860:feature/ic#diff-8613798e51e40568c4260ec96e3ed031R159)), but it is yet to be merged.

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the memory and CPU of the given template through using the same data sources as you are using. However it looks like you are using an older version of the provider plugin for vSphere.

Instead of using your current version, switch to the following version:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
  vsphere = {
    source = "hashicorp/vsphere"
    version = "2.1.1"
  }
 }
}
```